# Why does app built with Phonegap and Moobile freeze on alert sometimes?

Tags: mobile, cordova, mootools, phonegap-build

I went to http://moobilejs.com/#download, downloaded the Moobile 0.2.1 Boiler Plate (which is a mobile application framework built on MooTools), put the www files into Dreamweaver CS6, ran the Phonegap Build Service, scanned the QR code with my android phone, and installed the app.

I didn't make any changes to the code. It's just an app that has a single button that says Hello, which opens up an alert box. You can dismiss the alert box by tapping OK.

It works fine in the browser. And on my android phone it seems to work fine, but after tapping OK to dismiss the alert box, it comes back and you can't dismiss it. It doesn't always happen the first time you tap Hello, but eventually it always has this problem. Changing the orientation makes it go away, but it has the same problem the next time you tap Hello.

What could be causing this?

Edit: Here is the view:

```
<div class="hello-world-view">
    <div data-role="button" data-name="hello-world-button">Hello World</div>
</div>
```

Here is what's in app.js

```
if (!window.ViewController) window.ViewController = {};

var HelloWorldViewController = new Class({

    Extends: Moobile.ViewController,

    helloWorldButton: null,

    loadView: function() {
        this.view = Moobile.View.at('templates/views/hello-world-view.html');
    },

    viewDidLoad: function() {
        this.helloWorldButton = this.view.getChildComponent('hello-world-button');
        this.helloWorldButton.addEvent('tap', this.bound('onHelloButtonTap'));
    },

    destroy: function() {
        this.helloWorldButton.removeEvent('tap', this.bound('onHelloButtonTap'));
        this.helloWorldButton = null;
        this.parent();
    },

    onHelloButtonTap: function() {
        var alert = new Moobile.Alert();
        this.view.addChildComponent(alert);
        alert.setTitle('Hello');
        alert.showAnimated();
    }

});
```

Answer (score 1):

It has to do with the Moobile ScrollView class and IScroll.

Here's the fix from JP at Moobile...

1) Add the data-option-scroller="IScroll" attribute to scroll view elements

example `<div data-view="Moobile.ScrollView" data-option-scroller="IScroll">`

2) Add the following snippet at the top of your app.js file.

```
Class.refactor(Moobile.ScrollView, { 
options: {
scroller: 'IScroll'
}
});
```

Comment: I'm don't think I'm using a scrollview. I edited my question to include the view.